# SELECT statement causing Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction for innodb

Tags: mysql, timeout, locking

I am really wondering why this is resulting in “Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction”. This is innodb and default isolation level is REPEATABLE READ. AFAIK, SELECT statement should not give this error. Moreover, there is neither transaction nor "select for update" involved here.
Also there are no triggers involved on these 2 tables. autocommit is OFF.

Query:

```
SELECT cart.cart_id, profile_id,cart_data, cart.created_ts,
    cart.last_updated_ts, cart.last_updated_by, version, cart_item_id, cartItem.cart_id,
    cart_item_data, cartItem.created_ts, cartItem.last_updated_ts,
    cartItem.last_updated_by
FROM est_cart cart
LEFT OUTER JOIN est_cart_item cartItem
    ON cart.cart_id = cartItem.cart_id
WHERE cart.profile_id=:profileId
```

Here is how it has been retrieved in Java code.

```
 public Cart loadCart(String profileId) {
    try (Context time = loadCartFromDBTimer.time()) {
        MapSqlParameterSource sqlParameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        sqlParameterSource.addValue(PROFILE_ID, new BigInteger(profileId));
        return jdbcTemplate.query(cartDAOConfig.getFindCartByProfileId(), sqlParameterSource, new CartResultSetExtractor());
    } finally {
        logger.debug(FINALLY_BLOCK_CONSTANT);
    }
}
```

loadCart is not invoked within a transaction.

[image: tables]
Thanks in advance

Comment: More explanation required of problem to understand.

Comment: Are there triggers on any of the two tables involved in your query?

Comment: Either you are calling Lock tables explicitly from some other query on these tables in a different session. Or, you have triggers on them (as pointed out by @TimBiegeleisen)

Comment: There are no triggers on these 2 tables.